# How do I /actually/ link mp3 into html?

Tags: html, hyperlink, mp3

I've just started learning how to use this;  unsure on how linking audio files into the script works. All I'm trying to do is have a small audio player.

```
<audio controls width="100" height="100">
  <source src="somethin.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  <!-- Fallback for older browsers -->
  Your browser doesn't support html5 audio
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the file location.  For your script above you would put your somethin.mp3 in the same location as you html file.  If you want to put it in a sub folder (say your folder containing the .mp3 was called audio) it would be `<source src="audio/somethin.mp3" type="audio/mp3">`.  If it was in a second sub folder (say the second was called html_sound) then it would be `<source src="audio/html_sound/somethin.mp3" type="audio/mp3">`.  If you want to go one dictionary up you would use `<source src="../somethin.mp3" type="audio/mp3">`.  Two dictionaries up would be `<source src="../../somethin.mp3" type="audio/mp3">` and so on.

Just copy the dictionary name to go into a folder and use `../` to go up one folder.

also your code does not end with `</audio>` tag (It MUST) and it's `type="audio/mpeg"` not `type="audio/mp3"`.

Best test the script in Chrome, Edge or Internet Explorer (if you have Windows) are OK too but do **not** test it in Firefox or Opera as it supports .ogg files (I know W3schools says it does but all you need is an outdated browser and it will not work).

[You might want to check this out.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

If you have done links or images they are exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for the response; this seems more understandable now. ^^

Comment: @Nim Pleased to help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried checking w3 schools out?
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

There are ways to check for browsers in jQuery too. Make sure to check them out.

Comment: Yeah, I;ve had a look; but I'm more looking for how mp3's are put into html specifically... I can't get any scripts working...